# Static application.properties value works but dynamic one does not

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, application.properties

I'm using application.properties and my linux environment for some 12 factor goodness. I'm trying to get an api key to work for a custom application.properties value that I'm defining, but it is not working.

```
# application.properties

plenti.iaphub.webhooks.key=ACTUAL_VALUE_OF_API_KEY # This one works
```

```
# application.properties

plenti.iaphub.webhooks.key=${ENV_VARIABLE_HOLDING_API_KEY} # This one doesn't work
```

Here's how I'm trying to access the value

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/iap")
public class IAPHUBController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @PostMapping(path = "/webhook")
    public ResponseEntity<String> webhook(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") String iapAuthHeader) {
        String iaphubKey = env.getProperty("plenti.iaphub.webhooks.key");
        if (!iapAuthHeader.equals(iaphubKey)) {
            // this is an inauthentic request
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello IAPHUB");
    }
}
```

here's the error I get when I try to access the ENV variable version

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set an environment variable named `PLENTI_IAPHUB_WEBHOOKS_KEY`. This will override the value set in the *application.properties* file. You can do this for any property: convert it to uppercase and replace the dots with underscores.

Comment: checking for understanding. You're saying that if I set an environment variable on linux that is the same name as the `application.properties` but uppcase and with `.` replaced with `_` that will... just work?

Comment: the same as the value in _application.properties_, yes